# fetching column names of a join table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, alias

I have 3 tables in my database schema.
1. products
2. distributors
3. products_distributors

I used the following query to join these tables and get a resulting join table.

```
$query = "SELECT distributor_id,d.Name
FROM products p
INNER JOIN products_distributors pd ON p.id = pd.product_id
INNER JOIN distributors d ON pd.distributor_id = d.id  
          where product_id=1 ORDER BY d.Name";
```

I am able to display the data from this resulting table.

But I wish to display this data along with column names of this resulting table.

Please help me with the same.

I read somewhere how to display column names from stored tables in database. I found this.

```
$query = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'products'
    AND table_schema = 'my_database'";
```

I am not sure if this would work for the dynamically created join table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Column name can be fetched via **mysql_fetch_field**. Example code is available in http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-field.php.